# VBA copy a column from an excel's file to another in the first empty column

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim selection As Variant
selection = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 2) = selection
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
selection = Cells(1, 2)
namefile = "C:\Users\xxx\" & Left(selection, 1) & "\" & selection & ".xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=namefile



Dim wk1 As Workbook
Dim wk2 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet



Set wk1 = Workbooks("file1.xlsm")
Set wk2 = Workbooks(selection & ".xls")

Set sh1 = wk1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sh2 = wk2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sh2.Activate
Dim firstempty As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim A1 As Variant
Dim R1 As Variant
Dim C1 As Variant
x = 0
y = 0
While x = 0
If Range(Cells(1, y), Cells(1, y)) <> "" Then
y = y + 1
Else: Range(Cells(1, y), Cells(1, y)).Select
A1 = Target.Address
R1 = Target.Row
C1 = Replace(A1, R1, "")
firstempty = (C1 & ":" & C1)
x = 1
End If
Wend

With sh1

    .Columns("D:D").Copy Destination:=sh2.Range(firstempty)
End With


End
End Sub
```

I need to copy column D of Sheet2 file1.xls on the first blank column of sheet1 of a second file whose name is selected by a combobox.
I am having trouble defining the letter of the empty column of the second file.
I am getting runtime error 424 and my debugger brings me to the point in the code:
  A1 = Target.Address

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `Target` defined?

Comment: Is this code in `UserForm1' module?

Comment: I've defined target: Dim target As Variant . But i've the same error

Comment: Yes, the code is in UserForm1' module

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't y=0 be y=1 ?
Now you're referring to column 0.

And then this should work:

```
If Cells(1, y) <> "" Then
y = y + 1
Else
firstempty = y
x = 1
End If
```

And then:

```
.Columns("D:D").Copy Destination:=sh2.Columns(firstempty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much faster way to get the last column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim selection As Variant
selection = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 2) = selection
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
selection = Cells(1, 2)
namefile = "C:\Users\xxx\" & Left(selection, 1) & "\" & selection & ".xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=namefile



Dim wk1 As Workbook
Dim wk2 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet



Set wk1 = Workbooks("file1.xlsm")
Set wk2 = Workbooks(selection & ".xls")

Set sh1 = wk1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sh2 = wk2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastColumn As Long

LastColumn = sh2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

sh1.Columns("D:D").Copy sh2.Cells(, LastColumn)

End Sub
```

As a side note could you explain this part of code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 2) = selection
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
selection = Cells(1, 2)
```

It looks like you are getting a value then assigning the value to a cell then the cells value (that you just assigned already) back to the variable that assigned the original value.

at the most you should only need one line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = selection
```

dno't get the need for the rest.

Comment: I don't need exactly the last empty column, I need the last column with an empty first row

Comment: @user3023582 Thats exactly what this does, it goes to the last column in Row 1, then jumps left to the last value in Row 1 with a value, then moves over 1 to the empty cell next to it. The end command is the same as if you are on the worksheet press Ctrl + Arrow Keys.